# Java/Graphics: Plotting 3d coordinates?

Tags: java, 3d, plot, space

I'm coding a programm, that will produce 3d coordinates for a rocket and I would like to do a rudimentally graphic output for this.

it just has to be scaleable and rotationable, so that you can change the view manually.
the postions should be connected by lines and
it ould be nice to have spheres for earth and moon ( and perhaps addtional celestial objects).

I think, there should be some ready stuff for this kind of plott already available, but I couldn't find one.

So that's why I'm here to ask you, if you know such a thing.
and if there isn't I would kike to ask you how a bignner like me should start this?
I ust coded for console apllications, because there was no need for a real graphics output.

thank you in advance for any tip! :)

Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there are sand-box ready things you can use to draw customizable 3d objects in Java, if you can live without strange things you can you just a graph library able to draw 3d graphs like for example **jMathTools** ([link](http://jmathtools.berlios.de/doku.php?id=jmathplot:tutorial)).. otherwise you should go into J3D with opengl and similar things.

I don't think they exist just because doing simple things is trivial if you work with *OpenGL* or similar APIs..

Doing what you need with OpenGL is not complex at all, just a `GL_LINE_STRIP` to draw the trajectory and some primitives if you need earth, moon and so on.. rotating and scaling come implicitly moving the camera of your viewport..

Take a look at: [Java3D](http://java3d.j3d.org/) or [JOGL](https://jogl.dev.java.net/)

Comment: If you go for JOGL do it by modifying one of the demo apps.  Writing a JOGL app from scratch is tricky for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe nobody has mentioned this yet, but the NASA WorldWind project seems like exactly what you need: http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/  You can extend it with JOGL if needed, or you can use some of the vast modeling objects already available to mark trajectory and location in 3D coordinates, complete with zooming/rotating and the like.  Having accurate Earth layers is nice as well =)

Comment: hi, do you mean their xml support, or can I use NASA's globe in realtime by sendingmy stuff into their system? Andreas

Comment: The worldwind API will take care of rendering the Earth for you. You can create and add objects via their API.

Comment: Hi Jason, that was REALLY a good idea, thank you. I tested it and it was really easy. Now I have to go into further details, so that my coordinates can be displayed in "realtime", because I'm able to create all coordinates and to let them all displayed at once.
But nevertheless that was really helpfull.
next stepp will be to integrate some volumentric objects, because I want to have at least a sphere where the moon will be ;).
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Use JOGL! It is easy to install, and if you know Java it should be easy. There are a few things in JOGL that require you to be decent in trigonometry. This tutorial might help you get started: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rT02jFYrXv0